# "Open with Explorer" in Firefox

Tags: sharepoint-library

Majority of users are currently using Firefox. We are wondering if it's possible to enable the "Open with Explorer" option in document library.

Comment: No, this is an IE function.  I upvoted both the answers, because Chrome, Edge and FF do not support the ActiveX object used to launch Win Explorer.   Which makes me wonder what the future support model for Internet Explorer will be after they transition to the Chrome codebase.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is an Internet Explorer only function.

Answer (score 1):

This function is only available in Internet Explorer because it's using ActiveX.