# Open with Explorer in Microsoft Edge

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, open-with-explorer

As you all know; IE support is ending early next year and quite a few on-premise Intranets are integrating Microsoft Edge.
We were checking if it is possible to enable the "Open with explorer" ribbon option in Microsoft Edge.

A few resources have mentioned that it is an IE only option because of some ActiveX implementation there which modern browsers do not share.

["Open with Explorer" in Firefox](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/117208/101122)

But from Microsoft's documentation; they have mentioned how it would be possible in an SPO Tenant with Microsoft Edge. They mention:

a) configuring 'ConfigureViewInFileExplorer' policy in Edge and

b) running this Powershell SPO cmd: `Set-SPOTenant -ViewInFileExplorerEnabled $True`

So, i'm a bit confused now. Is it possible for Edge in the on-premises scenario too

**EDIT** - to allow connection via File Explorer

[image: Steps to Add a Network Location]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On-prem doesn't support this functionality, so you'd need to continue to use IE or initiate the process from Windows Explorer.

In Windows Explorer, you can "Add a network location" and enter the UNC (and if I recall, HTTPS://, location).

Comment: thank you!  Could you tell me how the process is initiated from Explorer?

Comment: I've edited my answer.